# ContactForm Plugin - Where does the email source come from?

Tags: plugin-contactform

Trying to find out where the source email comes from with the ContactForm Plugin. The plugin is perfect and saved me a lot of time, so thank you guys!

Alas, my client is getting emails from the site in my name, yet I can't see where this is being sourced form - except possibly my profile page.

Is there a place I can configure the email for the ContactForm plugin other than changing the email address for the admin account?

Many thanks,

Stephen

Comment: This is the value I'm feeding in on each form page:
       <input type="hidden" id="fromEmail" type="email" name="fromEmail" value="catering@flourish-uk.com" required>

It is appearing as my own pathfinder email when sent. I've cleared the caches to see if this helps.

Comment: Will the type email affect it, does it need to be type text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email's "from" field is set to the system email that is under `Settings->Email` in the control panel.

The email's "reply to" field is set to the "fromEmail" hidden input you set on the form.

This is done because many email servers will see that the "from" domain is different than the domain the email originated from and mark it as SPAM.

Comment: Many thanks Brad, a case of couldn't see the Wood for the Trees. Fixed!